# Easiest way to create gloves?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to create gloves for my character and decided to use simple solution - high poly cylinder and shrinkwrap modifier and it looks ok, but I have a problem with fingers:[image]
I suppose this is happening because of bad precision of modifier. How can I solve this problem? I've tried to apply subdiv modifier and got better result, but it still looks bad.

Comment: hello could you please share your file (only the arm and the cylinder)?

Comment: Judging by the image, you probably need more vertices. Try subdividing in edit mode.

Comment: @moonboots, sorry, I can't. The file is nsfw, and it's weight is ~500mb. I don't know why.  Seems like Alex's solution is pretty good, I'll try to use it today's evening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way would be to duplicate the hand, inflate it and smooth it using  sculpting tools

[image]

Comment: Cool, it works, but what to do with nails?

Comment: Well, I just manually selected nails, deleted it's vertices, and then used gridd fill with further sculpting. Thank you for your advice.